# Android: Differents font color for image and text in webview

Tags: android, image, text, webview

In my app, I have a webview that contains images and text.

I'd like the image (that is latex codecogs style, example: [example of latex codecogs image](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cinline%20a%5E%7Br%7D%5Cint%20t/8%207%5Ctfrac%7Bo%7D%7Bl%7D) ) to have a white font (If not, I can't really see the equation), and the text to have an other font (transparent).

My problem is that the image latex is really hard to see if I have a color font, but I need a color font for the other parts.

Is it possible?

Thank for your help

Comment: To clarify, Do you want to change the color of the font within the images...? or change the background color so the image text color is more legible

Comment: Yeah, within the image, cause the "equation image" is really bad quality and in gray, so I need the "within-font-image" to be white

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the font of the text in an image... in fact you cant alter the image like you wish as an android option... I would advise you change the font color in photoshop or something similar using a replace color function. you CAN, however, set background color and text color seperately for different pieces of text.

Comment: I think I will let it white, and if it's not ok, I can parse my html text and modify only the font of the part I want. Thanks for your help

Comment: yeah no problem. Sorry I couldnt be of more help... your 'image' is a png? jpg? if its html you are parsing you definitely can change the font.

Comment: You have the link on my first message. It's a gif or a latex type but I'm not sure. It's really boring, that's the only images that give me problems on my app

Comment: well, they are an image, not special ascii characters, so no luck parsing them. I would just post them on a photoshop forum and have someone swap the colors out for whatever you want. It will take anyone with photoshop 10 seconds

Comment: In fact I get lots of images like that, I don't have the list I just get some link, so I can't modify each image with photoshop